# I need a list of all of my PHP classes and the files they are in - can I do that in Netbeans IDE?

Tags: php, netbeans, ide

I am developing with PHP, using Netbeans as my IDE. I am not 100% sold on it, so my question can be answered in terms of Netbeans or another IDE or tool.

I have been really working more with oops lately in PHP. I am getting more complex in my project, and I basically put each Class into its own file.  I keep losing focus on my code however, as there are so many files and some of my classes are really tests. I can't easily tell the difference between what is real classes or what are just tests that I am not referencing any more.

I would like some sort of tree or listing that shows all the classes, starting at index.php and working thru every class/file used.

Comment: Not sure if Netbeans provides any support for this, but if you organize your codes in the first place and keep one class in one file, you should not have difficulty tracing them.

Comment: superuser.com , nothing to do programming ?

Comment: from now on you could name all you're test classes starting with `Test`, then an easy search thru project filles for `class Test` or `new Test` will reveal all you're test classes usage and files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Netbeans just for a couple small J2ME project, so I don't know much about its working. But in the PHP editor I use, Codelobster PHP Edition, there's a tab on the left of the page where you can have different views, such as project view (all folders and file of the current project as a tree menu), a file view (divided by resource type: vars, functions, interfaces,...) and also a Class View, that shows you all the method of all the classes inside your project, alphabetically ordered.
Dont'k know if you meant something like this, in case you could give it a try, it's free.

Comment: Thanks. Your post helped me. I tried CodeLobster, which I liked and it did indeed have a great class viewer. Also looking at Rapid PHP and some others now. I didn't realize how limited feeling for me netbeans is. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using [PHPdoc](http://www.phpdoc.org/)? You ought to.

Yes, it will give you what you asked for - and a whole lot more!